# submit button with no text or form name attribute

Tags: javascript

could someone help me with this question?

in JavaScript, we can use "document.HELLO.submit();" submit a form if the form name is HELLO. but i meet a case there's a button on webpage (the button itself doesn't have any text), has no form name found.

in what way in JavaScript i can simulate the submit action to this button?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all `<form>` elements by calling `document.getElementsByTagName("form")`.

Comment: You actually get an HTMLCollection that is also avialable as [`document.forms`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection).